# how to know,how many asynctask/service running in my current app programmatically?

Tags: android, api, service, android-asynctask

I am working on Api-call based.in that I am calling asynctask one after one and some other Api-call also.so I want to know how many api-call running in current app?can you suggest me to get total running api-call & kill to api-call.

***Your answer would be appreciated.***

Comment: what you want actually?

Comment: You could increment a count each time you make such a call, and decrease everytime the asynctask finishes.

Comment: I wann kill running asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with this way:

Every Async Task which you create should call method of your AsyncManagerSingleTon class which have array of pointers of your tasks, and when your Async-Tasks complete works they should notify (for example with some method call) your AsyncManagerSingleTon that this Async-Task finish work, and if you will need at runtime to stop some Async-Task, you can do it easy using pointer from array which stored in AsyncManagerSingleTon

Answer (score 0):

You may investigate stacktrace with the help of [getAllStackTraces](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces()).

But proper cancel/stop logic should be designed and implemented by developer.